# example for using dominant convergence theory and counterexample

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\mu$ be Lebesgue measure on $[0, 1]$. Let $g : [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be Borel measurable, and set $g_{n}(x) =g(\frac{nx}{n+1})$. Assume that $g$ is bounded, and that $g$ is continuous at $x$ for $\mu$-a.e. $x$

(i) Show that $\int_{0}^{1} |g_{n} − g|d\mu \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

(ii) Show, by example, that this conclusion may fail if we drop the hypothesis that $g$ is bounded.

For (i), I tried in this way:

Since $g$ is bounded, $g_{n}$ will be bounded too, which means $(g_{n} − g)$ is bounded(i.e. there is a $M$ such that  $|g_{n} − g|\leq M$)

Also, since $g$ is continuous and $\lim_{n \to \infty} g_{n}= g$, we can say $(g_{n} − g) \to 0$, as  $n \to \infty$.

Now by dominant convergence theory, we can say :

$\int_{0}^{1} |g_{n} − g|d\mu \to 0$

Is it correct?

For part (ii), i couldn't reach to any thing. I really appreciate that if you could help me.

Comment: There is no need to ask this question again! See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1041610/show-that-int-01-g-n-%E2%88%92-gd-mu-to-0-as-n-to-infty